# Excel hyperlink type of function with click event to do POST

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA function that does a POST to an ASPX page.  My goal is for it to work similar to the HYPERLINK function.  The function could be used an indefinite number of times in the spreadsheet and each time would be executed from a different cell address, and be passed a series of parameters (url, postdata, etc).  The function works fine except that it runs automatically instead of only when the user clicks on the active cell.

```
Function WinHTTPPostRequest(url, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, image, answer, linkDisplay)

  Dim http
  Dim formData As String
  formData = "&choice1=" & choice1 & "&choice2=" & choice2 & "&choice3=" & choice3 & "&choice4=" & choice4 & "&question=" & question & "&image=" & image & "&answer=" & answer
 formData = replaceSpaceWithPlus(formData)
 Call BrowserSend(url, formData)
 WinHTTPPostRequest = "Click Here"
End Function
```

After googling, what I've been able to find is only solutions with select/case statements for which cell was clicked and the click functionality is spreadsheet wide rather than active cell specific.  This needs to be a function the user can copy indefinitely (though in this case it will only be copied vertically in the same column).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with a slightly different Excel structure.  Say we place an **Inserted** hyperlink in a cell (that  is a hyperlink not using the =HYPERLINK() function).  The destination of the hyperlink would the the cell itself.  The "friendly name" would be your parameter list.

We would also include a hyperlink follow event macro.

So if we click on the hyperlink, we really don't jump anywhere.  Instead the event macro will be triggered.  The event macro will pick up your parameters and perform the POST.

**EDIT#1**:

Here is a simple example............pick a cell, any cell, and run this macro:

```
Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim subadd As String
    subadd = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Selection.Address(0, 0)
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        subadd, TextToDisplay:="P1,P2,P3"
End Sub
```

This places a hyperlink in the cell that goes absolutely nowhere!

Next place this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
    MsgBox ary(0) & vbCrLf & ary(1) & vbCrLf & ary(2)
End Sub
```

Now if you click on the cell, the event macro will be triggered; it will grab the parameters from the cell and do SOMETHING.

You, of course, will modify this event macro to perform your POSTing operation.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you give a simple example?  Thank you.

Comment: Okay.  That's really ingenious.  Thank you.  So to make sure I understand what's happening the "Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)" method executes after or follows the click event, is that correct?  I've tried it out and it works great, except I receive an error about the invalid URL used in the HyperMaker() routine.  Putting a real URL in of course defeats the purpose and sends the user off somewhere else.  I tried Application.DisplayAlerts = False in FollowHyperLink but it's too late by the time it reaches that code.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using in Hypermaker??

Comment: Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim subadd As String
    subadd = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Selection.Address(0, 0)

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        subadd, TextToDisplay:="Click Me"
End Sub

Comment: I originally left it exactly as you wrote it with P1,P2,P3 and it gave me the reference error.

Comment: Sorry.............i was not clear.....Rather than "Click Me", you need your parameter list like:   **url, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, image, answer, linkDisp**          The event macro will then be able to "gather" these values and run **BrowserSend**  as you originally want the function to do.

Comment: First, thank you for your time and help.  I think you were very clear, it just didn't seem to matter what I put in the TextToDisplay property.  I tried using parameters, but it's the Address property that seems to be generating the "Reference is invalid".  I tried just a simple URL instead of "Click Me" and it still generates the error.  The only way it goes away is when I provide a value for the Address property.